# Como bloquear accesos de un URL si no se ha logueado

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs

Tengo un proyecto en JavaScript que consume un API el cual manda un responseCode especifico y devuelve el rol, según ese rol, se redirige a la página que el usuario debería ver, pero necesito que al colocar el URL no le permita ver a menos que se haya logueado, si no se ha logueado, que lo regrese al login.

```javascript
if (code == 0) {

    console.log('Usuario existe con rol: ' + rol, ' El mensaje del API fue: ' + message);

    if (rol == 'Administrador') {
        window.location.href = 'support/management/dashboard.html';
    } else {
        window.location.href = 'support/user/home.html?auth=true';
    }
} else {
    console.log('No permisos');

    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: 'Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecto, verifique.'
    });
}
```

Esta sería la lógica básica de JavaScript, y me gustaría que cualquier página que no sea index.html no tenga acceso a menos que se haya logueado.

Comment: Depende... El login tambien lo haces contra esa API? Tienes algun endpoint en la api que te permita validar si el usuario esta logueado? El login es solo en el frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes guardar el rol en `localStorage`. Básicamente guarda datos que persisten ([acá más info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Guárdalo así

```
if (code == 0) {
    localStorage.setItem('rol', rol)
    // ... el resto de tu código
}
```

Luego en cada `html` puedes hacer obtener el `rol` desde el `localStorage`

```
const rol = localStorage.get('rol')
```

y validar de acuerdo a lo que necesites

```
if(rol === undefined) {
    //Significa que no se ha logueado porque no se ha guardado la variable
    window.location.href = 'login.html'
}
```

o

```
if(rol !== 'administrador') {
    //Solo administradores pueden ver esto
    window.location.href = 'index.html'
}
```

**NOTA**

La variable persistirá en `localStorage` hasta que sea borrada. Para eso puedes crear una acción de `log out` y una vez que lo hagas borrar la variable.

```
localStorage.removeItem('rol');
```

También si quieres que solo se mantenga la variable en lo que la pestaña está abierta y una vez cerrada se borre, puedes usar `sessionStorage` [(más info sobre sessionStorage)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: ¡Excelente!, era lo que buscaba, saludos!